# How do you find the probability of a type-II error occurring with an unknown sample mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Assume you are using a significance level of $α=0.05$ to test the claim that $μ<20$ and that your sample is a random sample of 33 values. Find $β$ given that the population actually has a normal distribution with $μ$<sub>1</sub> $=$ 15 and $σ=7$.

- These are me workings out up to the point that I got stuck

$H$<sub>0</sub> : $μ$ = 20

$H$<sub>1</sub> : $μ$ < 20

Firstly, I'm not sure if this is right. To work out $β$, we find P(Do not reject $H$<sub>0</sub>|$μ$ = 15)

So $\bar X$ = $20 + \frac{7}{33^{0.5}}(-1.96) = 17.61$

And I think I'm supposed to find the probability that $X > 17.61$ given $μ = 15$ and $σ = 7$ but I feel like it's wrong. If so, can anyone please point out where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Changed the null and alternative hypotheses

Comment: If the claim is $\mu < 20$, I might have presumed this was $H_1$

Comment: @Henry Uh, well I'm think I'm also confused as to what should be the null and alternative hypothesis at this point. So if μ<20 is the alternative hypothesis, then is the null μ = 20? Aside from that, is my working out valid?

Comment: @Henry I'm really confused on this, do you mind explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we determine the rejection criterion for the test.  Clearly, we are intending to use the one-sample $Z$-test:
$$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\bar X - 20}{7/\sqrt{33}}. \tag{2}$$  Then we will reject $H_0$ at level $\alpha$ if $$\Pr[Z < z_\alpha] = \alpha; \tag{3}$$ that is to say, if $Z < -1.64485$ for $\alpha = 0.05$.  (Note that your choice of $z_\alpha$ is incorrect because the test is one-sided, not two-sided.)  This in turn implies
$$\bar X < \frac{(-1.64485)(7)}{\sqrt{33}} + 20 \approx 17.9957, \tag{4}$$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean.

So if the sample is drawn from a normal distribution with mean $\mu_1 = 15$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 7$, the Type II error is given by
$$\beta = \Pr[\bar X > 17.9957 \mid \mu_1 = 15], \tag{5}$$ i.e., it is the probability of failing to meet the rejection criterion under the assumption that the alternative hypothesis is correct.  In this case, the alternative hypothesis is the point hypothesis $H_1 : \mu = \mu_1 = 15$.

Hence
$$\beta = \Pr\left[\frac{\bar X - \mu_1}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} > \frac{17.9957 - 15}{7/\sqrt{33}} \mid \mu_1 = 15\right] = \Pr[Z > 2.45841] \approx 0.00697778. \tag{6}$$

Comment: Ah I understand it now thanks. Follow up question, when I try to compute Pr[X¯>17.9957∣μ1=15], I don't get anywhere near the correct answer. When I use the standardized version I do, is there a reason for this or am I computing it wrong?

Comment: @BillCogn Because the standard deviation $\sigma$ is for a single observation, not for a sample of $33$ observations.  In other words, you're confusing the standard deviation and the standard error of the mean.  The sample mean $\bar X$ is a normal random variable with the same $\mu$, but its standard deviation (which is called the "standard error") is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I see now, thank you so much for showing me